# Is there a way to make the text size of special formatting like subscripts and superscripts larger?

Tags: feature-request, design, font-size

On Math Stack Exchange, people use a lot of sub/superscripts and it gets very difficult to read with how small the font sizes are. Even worse is when people make in-text vectors with subscripts (with size 12 font, the vector is in size 7, the vector subscripts are in size 6). Sometimes I have to zoom in 200+% just to be able to differentiate the letters.

I have tried this with and without glasses and both times I need to be within 1-1.5 feet (30-45 cm) of the monitor just to read, because the letters are so small.

If possible, I would like a setting that sets the default font size to something larger, because size 6 is impossible to read if you are within a reasonable distance from the screen. This is only an issue with the smaller subscripts and superscripts.

Comment: Are you asking *whether* there is such a setting (title) or *for* there to be such a setting (last sentence, tags)?

Comment: Most browsers allow setting a minimum font size. Does that not work for you?

Comment: If this is a feature request for the network, then please make it clear, if it's a question about browser settings, then please post on the [proper site](https://stackexchange.com/sites#name) and delete this one here. Also please take the tour and refer to the help centre on your chosen site *before* posting.

Comment: @Waterbloo Welcome to Meta SE. It's not clear if you want to increase all text sizes, or just some of those used in the math formatting, such as subscripts and superscripts. I assumed the latter and had posted an answer showing how to do this, but I have deleted it since I believe you're looking for something more general (however, if not, note you can right-mouse click any MathJax text, and then choose appropriate Math Settings | Zoom Trigger and Math Settings | Zoom values to allow you to optionally display any of just that text at a larger size).

Comment: @John Omielan I can read the regular text, but with the smaller fonts in mathematical notation its impossible to make out

Comment: @John Omielan here's an example of my issue https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2017579/finding-matrix-representation-of-t-relative-to-b-c

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing font size for equations on electronics SE (and others that are capable of equation generation)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233651/changing-font-size-for-equations-on-electronics-se-and-others-that-are-capable) . The question itself is a bit different from yours, as the OP there is asking about changing the font size to make the smaller text, like subscripts, more readable for them. Nonetheless, the [answer](/a/233654/562482) basically states what my answer here did (apart from not explicitly mentioning changing the zoom), plus some more.

Comment: @Waterbloo Thanks for updating your question and for providing the example. I agree the subscripts there are quite small, thus making them relatively difficult to read, at least compared to the other text. Thus, I assume my suggestion of changing the Zoom Trigger (and optionally the Zoom Factor) works for you. Since this was suggested in an answer to my suggested duplicate question, I thought it would make more sense to vote to mark your question as a duplicate than my undeleting my answer, which is really a duplicate of that other answer.

Comment: I see nothing small on your example question, even on my phone. Is it the case that you have less then average eyesight?

Comment: Can you add some ***example posts*** to your question? Aren't they supposed to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020), not subscript or superscript?

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum MathJax also makes use of superscript and subscript. The post John Omielan linked contains a perfect example.